# Add list within list while creating a new 'label'

Tags: python, list, append

I have 2 lists; or at least, I believe they are lists:

```
one = [{'sex': 'M', 'age': 22},
      {'sex': 'M', 'age': 76},
      {'sex': 'F', 'age': 37},
      {'sex': 'F', 'age': 45}]

two = [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

I want to append the list `two` to the list `one` while creating a new 'label'.

The desired output should look like this (and still be a list):

```
[{'sex': 'M', 'age': 22, 'new label': 0},
 {'sex': 'M', 'age': 76, 'new label': 1},
 {'sex': 'F', 'age': 37, 'new label': 0},
 {'sex': 'F', 'age': 45, 'new label': 0}]
```

This must be easy but I can't make it work and couldn't use closely related answers on so. Using just `.append(two)` put list `two` at the end of list `one` of course, instead of inserting it within list `one`.

Feel free to flag as duplicate if needed, but please help with this particular example! Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for d, v in zip(one, two):
    d["new_label"] = v

one
# [{'sex': 'M', 'age': 22, 'new_label': 0},
#  {'sex': 'M', 'age': 76, 'new_label': 1},
#  {'sex': 'F', 'age': 37, 'new_label': 0},
#  {'sex': 'F', 'age': 45, 'new_label': 0}]
```

Answer (score 2):

`one` is a list of [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). What you want to do is step through the dictionaries in said list, and append the values from `two` to it.

```py
for i in range(0,len(one)):
    one[i]['age'] = two[i]
```

This steps through each dictionary in the list, and appends your new key-value pair to it.

Comment: thank you very much! I accepted the first answer, but your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So the first one is a list of dictionaries and the other is a list.

```
one = [{'sex': 'M', 'age': 22},
  {'sex': 'M', 'age': 76},
  {'sex': 'F', 'age': 37},
  {'sex': 'F', 'age': 45}]

two = [0, 1, 0, 0]

for count, i in enumerate(one):
    i['new label'] = two[count]
```

That would be how I would do it. You can use enumerate to keep track of where you are in the loop.

Comment: thanks very much! I accepted the answer given first, but your help is much appreciated